# Delete specific record from pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have products stored in `products` table. Also I have order products stored in `order_product` table.

Assume I have product with id 53 for example, and I trash it. Then in `order_product` table I need to get specific record related with the product that I've trashed it. After I got the record, I should delete it. But it's not working if product is in trash. What's wrong and what needs to be done?

```
$product = Product::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
$orderProduct = DB::table('order_product')->where('product_id', $product->id); // it's not working if the product is in trash. 
if ($orderProduct) {
   $orderProduct->delete(); 
}
```

**[CASE CLOSED]**
I've found the problem. It's not working because above code is located inside `foreach`. Somehow it's not working. But after I move it outside `foreach`, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

best delete option add foreign key via migrations

```
Schema::table('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBiginteger('product_id')->nullable();
    ...
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

no need to write extra code to remove